# Execute SQL Task error -

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I get the following error when I call a stored proc within an execute sql task in SSIS.
"Description: Executing the query "Exec up_CallXXX" failed with the following error: "Incorrect syntax near '13'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly."
This is how it is set up:

ResulSet : None
ConnectionType : OLE DB
SQLSourceType : Direct input
SQL Statement : Exec up_CallXXX
IsQueryStoredProcedure : False
BypassPrepare : True

The stored proc runs fine when I execute it through SSMS.
Does anyone have an idea what is going on.

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the stored procedure or at least the query that's failing?

Comment: The window will not allow me to post the text of the entire stored proc.

Comment: Does the static value "13" appear in the text of the stored procedure?

Comment: Nope.
I can execute the proc by itself in SSMS, but when I call it via the execute sql task, it throws the error above

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a complete answer, but the quickest route to troubleshooting this problem is likely to be to capture the command that SSIS is actually trying to execute using a [SQL profiler trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175047.aspx), since I think SSIS uses sp_executesql to carry out "Execute SQL" tasks.

Once you have the text of the query SSIS is running, you may find that you can replicate the error if you execute it in SSMS.

I've had this kind of problem when the session settings for my SSMS session are different from the session settings used by SSIS/SSRS. Given the error message, it might be worth checking the `SET QUOTED IDENTIFIER` values in both sessions - but this is a guess.

Comment: I tried tracing it. But all the trace captures is the Exec up_CallXXX
in the text data.
There is no error information. or clue as to what and where its failing.

Comment: @sharadov - did you compare the session settings for the SSIS execution to your SSMS settings? Look for the "audit login" event corresponding to the package execution in the profiler trace.

Comment: @sharadov - is your SP executing dynamic SQL? That might be an alternative explanation for the error message when executing in SSIS.